# Best way of deleting SQL rows how i want

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i construct a SQL query to delete how i want.

I have two tables.
Table 1.
ID: Some Random Not Significant To This Question Columns : DateTime : UserID

Table 2.
ID: Some Random Not Significant To This Question Columns : DateTime : UserID

The two tables are related by DateTime and UserID

Is there anyway i can create a query so that it deletes from table 2 if no rows in table1 have a matching DateTime & UserID.

Thanks

Comment: i haven't but i believe it is down to my objective-c coding rather than the answers below. I'm aiming to get back onto it this afternoon. I did post my coding attempt to implement on a separate question but never got any replies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` :

```
DELETE table2 
FROM table2 t2 LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.`DateTime` = t2.`DateTime` 
                                  AND t1.`UserID` = t2.`UserID` 
WHERE t1.`UserID` IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE
FROM    table2 t2
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    table1 t1
        WHERE   (t1.userId, t1.dateTime) = (t2.userId, t2.dateTime)
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: create a backup before you delete lots of records :)

**The idea:**

```
DELETE FROM
   table1
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE table1.referenceColumn = table2.referenceColumn)
```

You can check which records will be deleted by replacing the `DELETE` with `SELECT *`

**And now the solution**

```
DELETE FROM
    table2
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM
            table1
        WHERE
            table2.UserID = table1.UserID
            AND table2.DateTime = table1.DateTime
    )
```